# auto reboot SLES11 SP1 as a VM

Tags: linux, vmware, virtual-machine, suse

I have a SLES11 SP1 (64bit) Linux installed as a VM with VMWare Player. I was trying to configure this Linux host for auto reboot after panic. For that, I added "kernel.panic=10" to  /etc/sysctl.conf. After reboot, when the host panic'ed, it did not reboot automatically. Does anybody has an idea ?
I tried installing SLES11 SP1 (64bit) on ESXi server as well, but same result. I could not get it to autoreboot after panic. 
I tried same settings with another distro (ubuntu 64bit), but these settings worked in that case.
If there is some other setting I need to do, please do let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For ESXi installation, you can trigger automatic reboot of guest virtual machine as follows:
Goto Configuration section -> Virtual machine startup/shutdown, and there you can add the virtual machine for automatic startup by clicking on 'Properties' button, so that it reboots automatically.  You can also define 'Startup delay' and 'Shutdown delay' for both 'Automatic startup' and 'Manual startup'.

Comment: This didnt work in my case. After panic the host still did not boot.

Comment: Try to change grub.conf by adding "panic=10" against the kernel you are using, if you have multiple kernels installed simultaneously, do it for all the kernels including the default one and see if it works then.